# Unembedding charts from graphs in powerpoint

Tags: excel, charts, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint deck prepared by a client that has over 50 charts copied in using an Excel data file I provided.

Unfortunately EVERY single chart in the PowerPoint has the entire Excel workbook embedded in it. Although the excel workbook is only ~200KB, since each chart has it embedded, the total file size of the PowerPoint deck is over 15MB!!

Is there any way for me to resolve this? Is there a way to Un-embed the workbook, while still keeping the charts?

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: Do you need to keep the charts editable?  If not, just ungroup them.  They'll become EMF pictures and the OLE data (ie, the workbook) behind them will be discarded.

Comment: You could also copy the embedded chart, then paste special as picture.